# Android getParentFragment() Null when inflating fragments directly from layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am creating a 'dynamic' ui with fragments, very similar to the example in Android's [Building a Dynamic UI](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) guide.  The difference being I am wrapping two fragments within a fragment rather than the activity.

The layout-large layout file for the right pane looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_message_multi_pane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/some_color"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_pane"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="com.rperryng.basicfragments.leftpane"

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/right_pane"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:name="com.rperryng.basicfragments.rightpane"

</LinearLayout>
```

the onAttach() method for the leftpane tries to call `mListener = (someInterface) getParentFragment()`.  However, when the layout is inflated with the large layout (i.e. on tablets), the `getParentFragment()` call is null (confirmed with an if statement and confirmation log message).  What gives? Is this due to the system not using the childFragmentManager when inflating directly from a layout or something? do I have to add the fragments at runtime instead?  Worth noting I am using the support library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The Android Support Library also now supports nested fragments, so you
can implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.

Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a 
<fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.
```

as talked about here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments